# Zend Framework : Failed opening required Zend/Loader.php (include_path='.:/php/includes')

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, centos

```
PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.:/php/includes')
```

I have installed ZF at CentOS, but facing this problem while calling

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'
```

I am using Zend Framework Version: 1.11.12

I tried to solve this problem using following processes:

Creating a Symlink Zend Framework on library path

```
ln -s /usr/share/php/Zend .
```

Copy Zend Framework on library path

```
cp -R /usr/share/php/Zend .
```

Not solved. How can i solve the error ?

Comment: The error says it all. .:/php/includes is just the directory in your php include_path. try adding the Zend directory in your include path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. 
your current include_path -> `(include_path='.:/php/includes')`
/php/includes is just the only directory in your php include_path. try adding the Zend directory in your include path or do it on the fly like below:

```
set_include_path('/path/to/ZendFramework-1.11.12/library/'.get_include_path());
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
```

Comment: i have several Zend path, /usr/include/php/Zend and /usr/share/php/Zend, /etc/php.d/Zend/library/Zend, which one should i include in php.ini file?

Comment: Not sure why you have the framework at multiple locations. However, Any one of those with valid Zend/library files should work.The error message doesn't show your added include path.Try restarting apache to make sure your changed php.ini is used.